# Not permitted to add eth0 to bond0

Tags: sudo, ip, routing, iproute, bonding

I'm trying to add an interface to my bond0 but I always get the error.

```
   sudo ip link set dev eth0 master bond0
  RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

I already tried it with sudo and with the root user neither worked.
Is my command wrong. I got it from here:
https://github.com/ebiken/doc-network/wiki/Linux-iproute2-:-ip-link-bridge-operations

Comment: some kernels appear to require the slave device to be down before it can be bound

Answer (score 1):

As was said in comment, try first make eth0 interface down and then add to the bond0. It helped in my case:

```
sudo ip link set dev eth0 down
sudo ip link set dev eth0 master bond0
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ("slave") interface (`eth0`) is down before you try to add it to the bond.

If it still doesn't work, it's possible your bond mode is not supported.
For me `balance-alb` won't work, but `balance-rr` will.
e.g.

```
$ sudo ip link add bond1 type bond miimon 100 mode balance-alb
$ sudo ip link set wlp0s20f0u1u1 master bond1
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
$ sudo ip link del bond1 
$ sudo ip link add bond1 type bond miimon 100 mode balance-rr
$ sudo ip link set wlp0s20f0u1u1 master bond1
$ # works!
```